# Query takes too much time with JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I need a little help improving the following query performance

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dle_pause 
       LEFT JOIN dle_post_plus 
              ON ( dle_pause.pause_postid = dle_post_plus.puuid ) 
       LEFT JOIN dle_post 
              ON ( dle_post_plus.news_id = dle_post.id ) 
       LEFT JOIN dle_playerfiles 
              ON ( dle_post.id = dle_playerfiles.post_id ) 
WHERE  pause_user = '2';
```

it takes `3 rows in set (0.35 sec)` the problem is with the third join. one of the rows don't have `dle_post.id = dle_playerfiles.post_id` so it scans whole the table.

looks like I have all needed indexes

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type   | possible_keys                    | key     | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dle_pause       | ALL    | pause_user                       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                              |      3 | Using where                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dle_post_plus   | ref    | puuid                            | puuid   | 36      | func                              |      1 | Using where                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dle_post        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                          | PRIMARY | 4       | online_test.dle_post_plus.news_id |      1 | NULL                                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dle_playerFiles | ALL    | ix_dle_playerFiles__post_id_type | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                              | 131454 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x2) |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------+----------------------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have an index on dle_pause.pause_postid and dle_playerfiles.post_id ? You have to get rid of the ALL type in your EXPLAIN query. It means a full table scan is done, and that's what makes it slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not put index on dle_playerfiles' post_id, then put index on it.
If you have already put an index on it, then in your query at last join write 'use index' like this:

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM 
     dle_pause 
   LEFT JOIN dle_post_plus 
          ON ( dle_pause.pause_postid = dle_post_plus.puuid ) 
   LEFT JOIN dle_post 
          ON ( dle_post_plus.news_id = dle_post.id ) 
   LEFT JOIN dle_playerfiles **use index(post_id)**
          ON ( dle_post.id = dle_playerfiles.post_id ) 
   WHERE 
     pause_user = '2';
```

This will use index for fourth table also. Right now your explain show that it is not using any index on fourth table and hence scans 131454 rows.

Comment: In my case it was a freakin mistake. instead of having post.id column with int type in both tables, I had varchar in one of them!

Comment: With this new query have you done 'Explain'? In result of explain whether key column shows index for fourth table, and how many rows are scanned now in rows column?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two alternative for solving this.

**First alternative:**

Create a temporary tables that contain only non NULL values for the key you comparing with LEFT join.

Something like this:

```
select *
into #dle_post_plus 
where pause_postid is not null
```

Do it for all three tables.

Then use your original query on the temporary tables which does not include NULL values.

**Second alternative:**
Create an index for each key you are comparing in the left join, in this way the index will do the job for you.

Off course you can always combine the two methods I suggested.